# Number of Paths from origin to a point

Tags: java

I need to calculate the number of paths from origin to a point(n,0) where n>0 and the number of moves must be exactly 2*n.
I can only move

(x + 1, y) [→], (x, y + 1) [↑],(x - 1, y + 1) [-], (x + 1, y - 1) [&], or (x + 1, y + 1) [%].

The restriction are:

[-] and [&] are never directly adjacent, in any order.

[↑] and [→] are never directly adjacent, in any order.

[↑] and [%] are never directly adjacent, in any order.

The program need to show all the moves(x>0 & y>0).
Example: For n = 7,(7) = 416449
I cannot get it to show the correct answer.

```
    package algo;

public class Test {
static int k = 0;

public static int calcul(int x, int y, int n, int pasi, int p, int[] num) {
    if (x ==n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n ) {
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=2*n;i++)
                System.out.print(num[i]);
            System.out.println(" ");
            k = k + 1;

        }
    } else if (pasi < 2 * n && x >= 0 && y >= 0) {

        if (num[pasi] != 2) {
            num[pasi + 1] = 1;

            calcul(x + 1, y, n, pasi + 1, 1, num);

        }
        if (num[pasi] != 1 && num[pasi] != 6) {
            num[pasi + 1] = 2;
            calcul(x, y + 1, n, pasi + 1, 2, num);

        }

        if (num[pasi] != 5) {
            num[pasi + 1] = 4;

            calcul(x - 1, y + 1, n, pasi + 1, 4, num);

        }
        if (num[pasi] != 4) {
            num[pasi + 1] = 5;

            calcul(x + 1, y - 1, n, pasi + 1, 5, num);

        }
        if (num[pasi] != 2) {
            num[pasi + 1] = 6;

            calcul(x + 1, y + 1, n, pasi + 1, 6, num);

        }

    }
    return k;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;
    int[] num = new int[n * 2 + 1];
    int q = calcul(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, num);
    System.out.println("paths:" + q);

}
```

}

Comment: So you are asking the people here to do your work?

Comment: You should try something to achieve this before asking. Please be sure to read How do I ask a good question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Write the code and we will help you!

Comment: I forgot to put my code,my bad.I really tried to do this but i cannot find a way to do it in a decent amount of time(1-10 sec).

Comment: You can remove `System.out.println(" k=" + k);` and your code will be considerably faster. If this is still not enough think about if you can cut off recursive calls when it is clear that the calculated path cannot reach its destination under the given constraints.

Comment: Also, are you sure that for _n=7_ there exist 416449 paths? I quickly calculated it and I think there are over 1.5M (I don’t tell you the exact number because I think this is some kind of homework :-).

Comment: The example is not made from my calculations but from the exercise so yes there are 416449 paths when n=7.

Comment: Oops, I ignored the constraints. Now for _n=7_ I get a lot less paths than 416k. Anyway, as for your code please check the condition `p != 1 || p != 6` which for logical reasons must always be `true`. This is probably a mistake.

Comment: I did the change but i doubt that the example is incorrect.I am still doing something  wrong and I think i know what.Whenever it comes back from a "bad move" it keeps the value of p of that move.

Comment: Also in your code there is a call `calcul(x, y - 1, n, pasi + 1)` which corresponds to down [↓] although you never described this as a legal move in your question.

Comment: I removed it in a previous edit.

Comment: I am afraid I can’t help you any further unless you have some example numbers for _n=2_ or _n=3_.

Comment: These are all the information I am given.I did the n=2 by hand and it's 3 if it helps and i changed the code.

Comment: Yep, my method correctly calculates 3. Therefore I believe your example for _n=7_ is wrong. By the way, why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote you,i have less than 15 reputation and i cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean isPossibleOrigin(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && pasi < 2 * n && (x+y)/2<2*n-pasi;
}

public static int calcul(int x, int y, int n) {
    if (x == n && y == 0 ) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, 0)) {
        return
              right(x+1, y, n,1)
            + up(x, y+1, n, 1)
            + leftup(x-1, y+1, n, 1)
            + rightdown(x+1, y-1, n, 1)
            + rightup(x+1, y+1, n, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
public static int right(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {


    if (x == n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, pasi)) {
        return
            right(x+1, y, n, pasi + 1)
                + leftup(x-1, y+1, n, pasi+1)
                + rightdown(x+1, y-1, n, pasi+1)
                + rightup(x+1, y+1, n,pasi+ 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
public static int leftup(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {


    if (x == n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, pasi)) {
        return
            right(x+1, y, n, pasi + 1)
                + leftup(x-1, y+1, n, pasi + 1)
                + up(x,y+1,n,pasi+1)
                + rightup(x+1, y+1, n,pasi+ 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
public static int rightup(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {


    if (x == n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, pasi)) {
        return
            right(x+1, y, n, pasi + 1)
            + leftup(x-1, y+1, n, pasi + 1)
                +rightdown(x+1, y-1, n, pasi+1)
                + rightup(x+1, y+1, n,pasi+ 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
public static int up(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {


    if (x == n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, pasi)) {
        return
            +up(x, y+1, n, pasi+1)
                + leftup(x-1, y+1, n, pasi + 1)
               +rightdown(x+1, y-1, n, pasi+1)
                ;
    }
    return 0;
}
public static int rightdown(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {


    if (x == n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, pasi)) {
        return
            right(x+1, y, n, pasi + 1)
           +rightdown(x+1, y-1, n, pasi+1)
                + up(x,y+1,n,pasi+1)
                + rightup(x+1, y+1, n, pasi + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Paths:"+calcul(0, 0, 1));
}
```

I think that the "?" can be replaced with "(x+y)/2<2*n-pasi" right?

Comment: Hint: Your formula does not consider the distance to the point _(n,0)_ but at the same time it depends on the number of remaining moves. So what is it that you want to check here?

Answer (score -1):

In general such problems can be solved by pure recursion without the need for `static` variables. Just count the number of paths for each possible continuation. Once you reach the desired destination under the given constraints increase the number of complete paths by 1 (`return 1;`), otherwise break the recursion by returning 0.

```
private static boolean isPossibleOrigin(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && pasi < 2 * n && ?;
}

public static int calcul(int x, int y, int n) {
    if (x == n && y == 0 && n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, 0)) {
        return
              right(x, y, n, 1)
            + up(x, y, n, 1)
            + leftup(x, y, n, 1)
            + rightdown(x, y, n, 1)
            + rightup(x, y, n, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For each possible direction write a similar method that takes into account its legal continuations.

```
public static int right(int x, int y, int n, int pasi) {
    x = x+1;

    if (x == n && y == 0 && pasi == 2 * n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isPossibleOrigin(x, y, n, pasi)) {
        return
            right(x, y, n, pasi + 1)
                + leftup(x, y, n, pasi + 1)
                + rightdown(x, y, n, pasi + 1)
                + rightup(x, y, n, pasi + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}

...
```

Finally, you can make a considerable performance boost by taking into account that visiting a node will not result in a complete path when its distance to the destination is greater than the number of remaining moves. I left a question mark at the spot that is a good place for you to add the appropriate condition to check this.